# GTK/C and GtkBuilder to make a single executable

Tags: gtk3, gtkbuilder

In my project I call `gtk_builder_add_from_file` function to load an xml file with the ui objects designed with Glade previously. So, I have my binary program and (in the same folder) the xml file.

What is the best way to pack all into a single executable? should I use a self-extracting script? or there is something else to compile all together?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `GResource` API available [in GIO](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GResource.html). GResources work by defining the assets you wish to ship with your application inside an XML file, similar to this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/com/example/YourApp">
    <file preprocess="xml-stripblanks">your-app.ui</file>
    <file>some-image.png</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

Take note of the `prefix` attribute, because it will be used later.

Once you've added your assets, you use the `glib-compile-resources` binary shipped by GLib to generate a C file that includes all your assets, encoded as byte arrays. The generated code will also use the global constructor functionality exposed by various compilers so that the resources are loaded once your application is loaded (and before `main` is called), or, in case of a shared object, once the library is loaded by the linker. An example of `glib-compiler-resources` invocation in a Makefile is:

```
GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES = $(shell $(PKGCONFIG) --variable=glib_compile_resources gio-2.0)

resources = $(shell $(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES) --sourcedir=. --generate-dependencies your-app.gresource.xml

your-app-resources.c: your-app.gresource.xml $(resources)
        $(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES) your-app.gresource.xml --target=$0 --sourcedir=. --geneate-source
```

Then you have to add the `your-app-resources.c` to your build.

In order to access your assets you should use the `from_resource()` function that is exposed in various classes; for instance, to load a UI description in `GtkBuilder`, you should use [`gtk_builder_add_from_resource()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-add-from-resource). The path used is a combination of the `prefix` you defined in the GResource XML file and the file name, e.g.: `/com/example/YourApp/your-app.ui`. You can also use the `resource://` URI when loading from a `GFile`.

You can find more information on the [GResources API reference page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-add-from-resource).