# new_from_file() in GTK -- do I always need that "glade" file? Can I embed it or something?

Tags: gtk, rust

In my Rust GTK app I have this, however, I think it goes for C++ as well:

```
let builder = Builder::new_from_file("main_window.glade");
```

When I compile my app in the release mode or maybe even in debug, I want to get rid of the necessity to distribute the executable file with the file "main_window.glade".

How I do link or embed the glade file into the executable statically?

Comment: You can embed it using [GResource](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/GResource.html) and `new_from_resource()`, assuming Rust can compile C files with compiler constructor directives side-by-side (or if there is a Rust version of the resource compiler). Or you can find another way to embed the binary in and use `new_from_string()`.

Comment: @andlabs, but can I load it statically? maybe as a string?

Comment: That's what I'm referring to; yes. GResources would be compiled directly into your program just like all the other object files, and `new_from_string()` loads it from... a string =P

Comment: @andlabs, thx, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rust standard library provides the [`include_str!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/macro.include_str!.html) macro, which lets you include the contents of a file into your program as a static string (`&'static str`), which you can then assign to a global constant.

```
const MAIN_WINDOW: &'static str = include_str!("main_window.glade");
```

Then, you can use [`Builder::new_from_string`](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/struct.Builder.html#method.new_from_string) to build the UI with that string:

```
let builder = Builder::new_from_string(MAIN_WINDOW);
```

If you would only use the constant once, then you can just use `include_str!` directly:

```
let builder = Builder::new_from_string(include_str!("main_window.glade"));
```

Comment: I like this approach better than mine, because there are fewer steps of indirection. The one feature GResource has that I don't see in include_str is built in compression and minification. So if executable size is an important factor it might be worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is [GResource](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html) which is part of GIO. You have to construct an XML file as explained in the description of the object, and then compile it using [glib-compile-resources](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/glib-compile-resources.html). [Here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html) is another page which calls out something like a typical workflow for GResource use. A similar stack overflow question was also asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855850/gtk-c-and-gtkbuilder-to-make-a-single-executable).

Comment: Has anyone got a "how to" for doing this with Rust?