# GTK+ Tutorial Compile error

Tags: compiler-errors, gtk, gtk3

I am trying to complete the GTK+ Tutorial on https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html, but when I compile the code I get the error -pthread: command not found. I am using Ubuntu 17.04. My compile command is:

```
    `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o exampleappwin exampleappwin.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

I downloaded the files from: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/examples/application3, so I know they are correct. Thanks in advance.

Adding to this based on the comments below. Received the error:

```
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':

   (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Then when I compile main, I receive the error:

```
    /tmp/ccMOUa6f.o: In function `main':

    main.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `example_app_new'

    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You forgot to specify the compiler.

Comment: example: `gcc -o exampleappwin exampleappwin.c \`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0\`` (where gcc is the compiler as andlabs mentioned)

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I did that! I always put that in the comments so I can cut and paste. Ok. I received an error: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.`  When I try to compile main, I receive an error: `/tmp/ccMOUa6f.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `example_app_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you mentioned is part of a bigger set of examples and it's prepared to be used with Make or Meson issued from the parent directory/folder.

If you want to compile "by hand", then you must notice that there are resource files that need to be dealt with.

[The files mentioned on the question above](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/examples/application3):

```
[...]$ ls
exampleapp.c              exampleapp.h     exampleappwin.h  Makefile.am       meson.build
exampleapp.gresource.xml  exampleappwin.c  main.c           Makefile.example  window.ui
[...]$
```

To compile just the example, then you should do:

```
gcc -o exampleapp main.c exampleapp.c exampleappwin.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

This will compile but when you run it, warnings will show up due to missings resources.

```
./exampleapp 

(exampleapp:4171): Gtk-CRITICAL **: Unable to load resource for composite template for type 'ExampleAppWindow': The resource at '/org/gtk/exampleapp/window.ui' does not exist
(exampleapp:4171): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child_full: assertion 'widget_class->priv->template != NULL' failed
(exampleapp:4171): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_init_template: assertion 'template != NULL' failed
```

Now you should prepare the resources (will create resources.c):

```
glib-compile-resources exampleapp.gresource.xml --target=resources.c --sourcedir=. --generate-source
```

and then recompile (adding the above resources.c file) :

```
gcc -o exampleapp main.c exampleapp.c exampleappwin.c resources.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

The warnings should disappear and the window  must contain an headerbar.

You can find more information about compiling resources, on this question:
[GTK/C and GtkBuilder to make a single executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855850/gtk-c-and-gtkbuilder-to-make-a-single-executable) but notice that you should use a build tool like Make or Meson as the project already has.

Another option would be to download the examples project and build them all.

Comment: Ok. I did that and everything seems to work well so far. Thank you very much. Sorry for the first post. I still can't believe I did that. Bookmarked the page. Thanks again. I really appreciate it. I did build them all for the record. Using them to learn GTK.

Comment: @Guest123ABC Glad it worked and feel free to ask questions as you learn GTK. If this answer solved your question feel free to accept it as correct. Good luck

Comment: I tried to uptick your answer, however I have less that 15 reputation. It said it counted the uptick, but will not show until get higher reputation. :)